# AJAX AnimationExtender weird problem with Intellisense

Tags: asp.net, ajax, animation

I'm new to AJAX but I have managed to get the ModalPopupExtender to work. Now the next step is to animate it. I would like to use AnimationExtender to do that.

The problem that I'm having is quite weird, I can't find anything about it on the net.

The code is simplified

```
<asp:AnimationExtender ID="AnimationExtender1" runat="server">
    <Animations>
         //Here would be something like <OnMouseOver> or something like that.
    </Animations>
    </asp:AnimationExtender>
```

There is no intellisense inside the  tag. Nothing happens when I'm trying to use it. Any suggestions about this ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the tagPrefix causes this. I was about to write what I have personally done, but someone has an entry about it [here](http://www.comanswer.com/question/how-to-fix-the-html-intellisense-in-asp-net-ajax-controls-or-pages).

Comment: I've tried this now. The master page is open and i have moved the tag register into the web.config. Doesn't change anything.

Comment: did you change it from asp to something else, like ajax

Comment: <add tagPrefix="ajax" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />   --- I have also tried to reset the settings for VS2010, the same. But its only this controller, i think anyway